# How to Open popup without postback in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to open pop-up using below code;

```
<div id="iyzipay-checkout-form" class="popup"></div>  
<asp:Button ID="btn999" runat="server" Text="BUY" OnClick="btn999_Click" />
```

btn999_Click event is like below;

```
public void btn999_Click()
{
   //some codes for checkoutFormInitialize
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", checkoutFormInitialize.CheckoutFormContent);
}
```

It shows the popup after the whole page postback which is not seems good.

Update Panel doesn't work because of popup shows with the modal background.

How can i make it without refreshing whole page ?

**EDIT 1**

I tried to use pagemethods. However this didn't work;

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
...
..
..
</form>
```

Comment: You could [try pagemethods](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/08/28/creating-and-consuming-aspnet-ajax-page-methods.aspx)

Comment: @Crowcoder didn't understand the usage. How this help for me ?

Comment: page methods don't postback, they are ajax calls wrapped up for you so you don't need to know much about ajax.

Comment: @Crowcoder this didn't work. I mean didn't make post back but popup didn't show up.

Comment: You can't put JS on the page?

Comment: @wazz well, i need to get values on click. How can i get it that values with js ?

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote you could make use of update panel, but you have to add aditional javascript function:

```
function HidePopup(modalId) {
    $(modalId).modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
}
```

which will close Popup and remove modal-backdrop from the page. You could call it with ScriptManager/ClientScript.

If you don't want to use updatepanel.
You can make use of jQuery AJAX (UpdatePanel is Microsoft AJAX which is deprecated) and create method that you will call to return values and assign it with jQuery.